# Delay the return of a function

Tags: javascript, delay, settimeout

Is there anyway to delay the return of a function using `setTimeout()`?

```
function foo(){
  window.setTimeout(function(){
      //do something
  }, 500);
 //return "something but wait till setTimeout() finishes";
}
```

Comment: The *setTimeout* call won't start until the current function has finished, so if the current function is waiting for *setTimeout* to return it will have a very long wait... :(

Answer (score 6):

Using promises:

```js
const fetchData = () =>
  new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(apiCall()), 3000);
  });
```

<sub>Answer updated thanks to @NikKyriakides who pointed out async/await is not necessary. I initially had `async () => resolve(await apiCall())`.</sub>

Comment: You don't need to `async/await`. Just: `setTimeout(() => resolve(apiCall()), 3000);`

Comment: You're right @NikKyriakides! Thank you. Will update my answer.

Comment: new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(() => resolve(apiCall()), 3000);
});
Corrected typo with missing parenthesis.

Answer (score 4):

You don't want to "delay" the code, because it would lock up the browser thread making your entire browser unusable until the your script's timeout has passed.

You can either set up an events which listens to a signal fired up after some time has passed. jQuery `.bind()` and `.trigger()` is what you want http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Or, you could use a callback function to work with the data you want after the time has ellapsed. So if what you intended to be like this:

```
function myFunc() {
  doStuff();
  result = delayProcess(5000);
  $('#result').html(result);
}

function delayProcess(delay) {
  // magic code that delays should go here
  return logic;
}
```

Should be something like this:

```
function myFunc() {
  doStuff()
  delayProcess(5000, function(result){ // Notice the callback function pass as an argument
    $('#result').html(result);    
  });
}

function delayProcess(delay, callback) {
  result = logic;
  setTimeout(function(){
    callback(result);
  });
}
```

Comment: That's the same as calling *setTimeout* from *myFunc*, except that in the above *result* becomes a global variable the moment something is assigned in the *delayProcess* function.

Answer (score 3):

`.setTimeout()` is for running a complete function after a timeout. It is ***not*** for delaying code.

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Window.setTimeout

A good link would be: [What is the JavaScript version of sleep()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/javascript-sleep/951033#951033)

*(A good question to ask is why do you need your function to sleep?)*

Answer (score 1):

Just call the thing you want to happen after the timeout in the end of the timeout function as below:

```
function foo()
{ 
    window.setTimeout(function()
    { 
        //do something

        delayedCode(returnValue); 
    }, 500); 

    return
}

function delayedCode(value)
{
    // do delayed stuff
}
```

Rather than returning.  Put the code that relies on the return value into `delayedCode()` and pass in the parameter to the function.